# Named credential JWT is not appearing in Authorization header in callout

Tags: callout, namedcredentials, jwt, authorization

I've configured a Named Credential to use the JWT authentication protocol (not JWT Token Exchange), but when the component makes a call to my service using the named credential, I don't get the JWT as an Authorization header. I checked all the headers, and don't see an "Authorization" header at all.

When I change the authentication type to basic or JWT Token Exchange, then it works, sending the values I expect.

Should there be a JWT in the Authorization header?

Do I have my issuer and audience set up correctly? When I experimented with JWT token exchange, it seemed picky about those.

> Certificate:  (empty)
>
> Identity Type:    Named Principal
>
> Authentication Protocol:  JWT
>
> Issuer:   <the host name of my Salesforce instance>.lightning.force.com
>
> Named Principal Subject:  <my user name>
>
> Audiences:    https://<the base URL of the remote server>
>
> Token Valid for: 10 Seconds
>
> JWT Signing Certificate:  My_Sample
>
> Generate Authorization Header:    checked
>
> Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header:    checked
>
> Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body:  checked
>
> Outbound Network Connection:  blank

My Apex code (actually written by someone else a long time ago), which works for Basic Authentication

```
      HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
      String statusApi = 'callout:my_named_connection/api/status';

      request.setEndpoint(ApiProxy.appendUrlParams(statusApi, request));
      request.setMethod('POST');
      request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      request.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueof(body.length()));
      request.setBody(body);  

      request.setTimeout(10000);
      HttpResponse  response = http.send(request);
```

Comment: The `Certificate` field is for callout endpoint, you want to leave that blank. Did you check `Generate Authorization Header` ? Please edit your question and include the Apex snippet that uses your NC.

Comment: Done. It uses Basic Authentication now; I'm thinking that I should be able to just switch the named credential to JWT without making a code change. Is that right?

Comment: Edited to clarify I'm not getting an Authorization header at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get a "JWT" header, because JWT typically (and in the case of Salesforce) uses the "Authorization" header with the Bearer scheme. The Authorization header contains all the JWT information needed. There is no "JWT" in the "Authorization" header itself, because a) it's Base64 encoded and b) does not state "JWT" as such in its three constituents.

Take the HTTP request generated by Salesforce, copy the long string after "Bearer" and get it decrypted and split up into its parts for example here:

https://jwt.io/

Explanations of the elements can be found in the relevant RFCs [7515](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html//rfc7515) and [7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519).

Decoding the bearer and finding its elements in the spec helps answering the other questions.

E.g. you will have noticed that Salesforce's "Issuer" becomes "iss" in the (decoded) Bearer token; one RFC uses "joe" as an example for a possible value, but it can be any "StringOrURI". You could provide an URI (which should be "https://...my.salesforce.com", not "... lightning..."), but I'd suggest a Salesforce user name. This is "OPTIONAL"; I don't know your endpoint provider, but if you are not told explicitly otherwise, the success of the communication should not depend on it.

Salesforce's "Audience" is "who or what the token is intended for". (The Bearer token has "aud" and this is only described by RFC 7519.) Although also optional, it is more often decisive. It is also "StringOrURI". `https://<the base URL of the remote server>` looks alright to me.

Finally, the decoded Bearer token has `typ: "JWT"` - the closest you can get to what you were looking for.

I'd uncheck the two check boxes for "Merge Fields". At least the code you provided doesn't show any use of [merge fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm).

Comment: Thank you! I will try unchecking the "merge fields" and see if that helps. To be clear, I'm not getting an "Authorization" header at all.

Comment: I can not imagine any reason why you shouldn't get an "Authorization" header, when "Generate Authorization Header" is checked. I've played with this yesterday while writing this up and did get the Authorization header nicely. Un-checking "Allow Merge" is unlikelyto make a difference. How do you verify the headers? Suggestion: Configure "http://httpbin.org/headers" as your endpoint of a test Named Credential (and as a Remote Site in SF's Setup), change the HTTP method in Apex to GET and System-debug the response body.

Comment: Thank you! Does Salesforce not support an Authorization header, or "JWT Token", for POST? I can test with GET, but in the end we do POST data to our server.

Comment: Salesforce creates Authorization headers for POST as well, no problem with that. The following endpoint returns your POST request: https://httpbin.org/anything .